# R - Subset rows of a data frame on a condition in all the columns

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I want to subset rows of a data frame on a single condition in all the columns, avoiding the use of `subset`.

I understand how to subset a single column but I cannot generalize for all columns (without call all the columns).

Initial data frame :

```
  V1 V2 V3
1  1  8 15
2  2  0 16
3  3 10 17
4  4 11 18
5  5  0 19
6  0 13 20
7  7 14 21
```

In this example, I want to subset the rows without zeros.

Expected output :

```
  V1 V2 V3
1  1  8 15
2  3 10 17
3  4 11 18
4  7 14 21
```

Thanks

Comment: please elaborate your question a bit further. For example, what is the subsetting condition?

Comment: @lmo It almost looks as though the rows being retained are in ascending order, but not quite.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Another potential pattern is to drop all rows that contain a 0.

Comment: An apply function can help `mydf [ !apply(mydf, 1, function(x) any(x == 0)), ]`

Comment: I edit the question to clarify the condition : indeed, I want to drop all rows that contains zeros.

Comment: Try `df[!rowSums(df == 0),]`

Comment: @StevenBeaupré a little code golf? `df[!rowSums(!df),]` :)

Comment: @PierreLafortune Lovely pitching wedge there ;)

Comment: @Kumpelka Please mark a solution as answer, if you have found a correct one else update your question accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
# create your data
a <- c(1,2,3,4,5,0,7)
b <- c(8,0,10,11,0,14,14)
c <- c(15,16,17,18,19,20,21)
data <- cbind(a, b, c)

# filter out rows where there is at least one 0
data[apply(data, 1, min) > 0,]
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution using `rowSums` function after matching to `0`.

```
# creating your data
data <- data.frame(a = c(1,2,3,4,5,0,7), 
                   b = c(8,0,10,11,0,14,14), 
                   c = c(15,16,17,18,19,20,21))

# Selecting rows containing no 0.
data[which(rowSums(as.matrix(data)==0) == 0),]
```

Another way

```
data[-unique(row(data)[grep("^0$", unlist(data))]),]
```